# I can't draw responsive custom button with Path in SwiftUI ( I used Paint Code)

Tags: swiftui, path

I was using PaintCode app for line to code.
But I can't use this code.. Because this code is not responsive.. I don't want button sizes to be static.
I don't want to give a static number. How can I make responsive button with Custom Path ? You can download SVG file below

```
struct BarButton: Shape {
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - 14, y: .zero))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 121.63, y: 11.28), control1: CGPoint(x: 116.2, y: -0.69), control2: CGPoint(x: 121.6, y: 4.65))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 121.07, y: 14.95), control1: CGPoint(x: 121.63, y: 12.53), control2: CGPoint(x: 121.45, y: 13.76))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 116.14, y: 30.58))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 104.63, y: 38.97), control1: CGPoint(x: 114.56, y: 35.6), control2: CGPoint(x: 109.89, y: 39))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 11.02, y: 38.44))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: -0.91, y: 26.44), control1: CGPoint(x: 4.42, y: 38.4), control2: CGPoint(x: -0.91, y: 33.04))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: -0.91, y: 11.81))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 11.04, y: -0.19), control1: CGPoint(x: -0.91, y: 5.21), control2: CGPoint(x: 4.43, y: -0.16))
        
        return path
    }
}

struct BarButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        BarButton()
            .frame(width: 125, height: 40)
//            .background(Color.orange)
    }
}
```

[image]

WeTransfer File Link for SVG:

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3cc5bab61ce0c676c95c3a8fbd3bd4cf20220506201936/9d9ce6

Comment: Change the hard coded values to percentages or if you have the svg just use the svg

Comment: I will use animation on button. :(

Comment: PaintCode used to have options for relative points rather than absolute.